# How can I sort on the results of a case statement in Spring Data?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

we have a UI sortable table that is backed by the following query, clicking a column does `order by` ascending or descending on that column. Problem is that one of the columns either renders the the users role name or their human name dependent on a conditional, and we need to be able to sort that column.

currently this the repository definition

```
Page<UserActivityLog> findByActivityTargetUserId( Long id, Pageable pageable );
```

I'm trying to write a specification that's looks more or less like this.

```
private static class UserSpecification implements Specification<UserActivityLog> {

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(
            final Root<UserRelatedEntity> root,
            final CriteriaQuery<?> query,
            final CriteriaBuilder cb )

     cb.selectCase()
     .when( root.<Boolean>get( "user.setting.fieldBoolean" ), 
         root.<RoleType>get( "user.role.roleTypeEnum" ).toString() )
     .otherwise( root.<String>get("user.humanNameString") )
... //magic
```

this is obviously incomplete. I'm not sure how to take this (assuming it's right for the case statement I want to do) and make it return the `Predicate`. I may not even be able to use the `Specification` to add the case statement, though I suspect I can. I'm also unsure of once I get it to work, how I'll pass the "field name" to a `Sort` (I know how to pass a field name, I guess I'm just not sure how to figure out what the field name will be).

It's worth saying I don't really understand the `CriteriaBuilder` api yet.

**Update** slightly modified example of a case statement that I grabbed from a [an oracle tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0040__Query-Select/Combineorderbyclausewithcasestatement.htm) which demonstrates what I need to do, I don't need the results of the case-ed column in my return object though.

```
SQL> select job, ename
2  ,      case
3           when msal <= 2500
4           then 'cheap'
5           else 'expensive'
6         end         as class
7  from   employees
8  where  bdate < date '1964-01-01'
9  order  by class;
```

How can sort my results based on a case statement generated field while still using a Spring Data repository?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing. I needed to fetch each attribute at a time (not obvious by tutorials imho) and then at the end in order to return a predicate I have created another specification which I delegate to which has the actual where clause (in this case a simple by id). It's worth saying that the `.Index.NAME` stuff is just a static string that contains the property name, we haven't decided whether to generate the metamodel yet.

```
public class FilterByIdForUserSpecification<AL extends AbstractActivityLogWithSiteUser> implements Specification<AL>
{
private final Sort.Direction direction;
private final Specification<AL> specification;


public FilterByIdForUserSpecification(
        final Specification<AL> specification,
        final Sort.Direction direction )
{
    this.specification = specification;
    this.direction = direction;
}

@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(
        final Root<AL> root,
        final CriteriaQuery<?> query,
        final CriteriaBuilder cb )
{
    Path<Object> siteUser = root.get( AbstractActivityLogWithSiteUser.Index.USER );
    Path<Object> ownerOrg = siteUser.get( SiteUser.Index.PRI_ORG ).get( Organization.Index.OWNER );
    Path<Object> fullName = siteUser.get( SiteUser.Index.CONTACT ).get( Contact.Index.FULL_NAME );
    Path<Object> roleDisp = siteUser.get( SiteUser.Index.ROLE ).get( Role.Index.DISPLAY );

    Expression<Object> queryCase = cb.selectCase()
            .when( cb.equal( ownerOrg, true ), roleDisp )
            .otherwise( fullName );

    query.orderBy( direction( cb, queryCase, direction ) );
    return specification.toPredicate( root, query, cb );
}

static Order direction( final CriteriaBuilder cb, final Expression<?> e, final Sort.Direction direction )
{
    if ( direction == Direction.ASC )
    {
        return cb.asc( e );
    }
    return cb.desc( e );
}
}
```

Comment: Vote up, saved my day.

Comment: Exactly what I need....saved me from switching to jpql :)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [Jpa Meta Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjrij.html) it will hel alot with `Specifications`, I am not sure if I understand your but here is an example that could help.

```
    public abstract class ASpecifications{
       // filtering by Option 1 

       public static Specification<A> findByOption1(final String opt1) {
            return new Specification<A>() {

                @Override
                public Predicate toPredicate(Root<A> root,
                        CriteriaQuery<?> arg1, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                    return cb.equal(root.get(A_.op1), prop);
                }
            };
        }

   // filtering by option 2

       public static Specification<A> findByOption2(final String opt2) {
            return new Specification<A>() {

                @Override
                public Predicate toPredicate(Root<A> root,
                        CriteriaQuery<?> arg1, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                    return cb.equal(root.get(A_.opt2), prop);
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

You can define a Pageable this way :

```
PageRequest request = new PageRequest(pageNumber - 1, PAGE_SIZE,   Sort.Direction.DESC,"optionTOSort");
```

And pass it to yourService class

```
    import static ASpecifications.*;
    import  static org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications.*;

    public class YourService {

    // autowire repository 

    public Page<A> filter(String opt1,String opt2,Pageable pageable){
    Specifications<A> spec = null;

             if(opt1!=null){
                 spec = where(findByOption1(opt1));
              }
              if(opt2!=null){


                 spec spec == null ? where(findByOption2(opt2))  : spec.and (findByOption2(opt2));
              }

         repository.findAll(spec,pageabl);
    }

}
```

Comment: I attempted to clarify the question with a sql example so that you can better understand what I'm trying to do. I'm sure that doing it is possible somehow since both jpql and criteria builder support case statements, it's just a matter of finding the right incantation